# Clarification on Polynomial operations

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

The polynomial $K[X]$ is of the form:

$$p=p_{0}+p_{1}X+p_{2}X^{2}+\cdots +p_{m-1}X^{m-1}+p_{m}X^{m}$$

where the $p$'s are elements of some field $K$ and $X$ are from elements of a ring $Y$.

I'm wondering about the operations *between* the field $K$ and the $Y$. Specifically we have *multiplication* $p_mX^m$. Since $K$ is a field, it has multiplication defined for elements in $K$. Likewise, $Y$ has multiplication defined for elements in its ring. But wondering where the multiplication is defined *between* $K$ and $Y$, since they are elements from different sets. Wondering if this means that you have a *third* multiplication defined for between $K$ and $Y$. So then you have $KK$, $YY$, and $KY$. I haven't read anywhere the rules for how this inter-set operation is supposed to be defined and if it differs from the single-set multiplication operation.

Also wondering if $p$ and $X$ can be from the same field.

Comment: Where did you get this definition?  This is not the usual definition at all (in particular, the usual definition does not involve any ring $Y$).

Comment: I made the $Y$ part up, because [it says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring) "a polynomial ring or polynomial algebra is a ring (which is also a commutative algebra) formed from the set of polynomials in one or more indeterminates (traditionally also called variables) with coefficients in another ring, often a field." So there were two rings, my mistake. I made it up b/c don't know where $X$ elements come from, I thought that was from a ring.

Comment: The polynomial K[x]? K[x] is a polynomial ring, why you write after is the general fork of one of its elements, but K[x] is the collection of all of them, along with rules for how to add and multiply (it’s a ring).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ring $Y$ involved here.  Instead, $X$ is treated as a formal symbol, and you multiply expressions $$p=p_{0}+p_{1}X+p_{2}X^{2}+\cdots +p_{m-1}X^{m-1}+p_{m}X^{m}$$ formally using the ring axioms.  In particular, for instance, the outcome when you mutliply an element $a\in K$ by $X$ is just $aX$: that's an expression of the form above with $m=1$, $p_0=0$, and $p_1=a$.

To be completely precise, an element of $K[X]$ can be defined as a function $p:\mathbb{N}\to K$ such that $p(n)=0$ for all but finitely many $n$.  We think of this function as representing the expression $$p(0)+p(1)X+p(2)X^{2}+\cdots$$ (where the sum eventually ends because $p(n)=0$ for all but finitely many $n$).  Addition of polynomials is defined by $(p+q)(n)=p(n)+q(n)$, and multiplication is defined by $(pq)(n)=\sum_{m=0}^np(m)q(n-m)$.  This multiplication formula may look strange but it is exactly what you get by multiplying polynomials like you would in high school: to find the coefficient of $X^n$ in $pq$, you add up all ways to make an $X^n$ term by combining an $X^m$ term from $p$ with an $X^{n-m}$ term from $q$.

Thinking of polynomials as functions in this way, "$X$" is just a shorthand for the function $p$ such that $p(1)=1$ and $p(n)=0$ for $n\neq 1$.  An element $a\in K$ can be considered as a "constant polynomial" by identifying it with the function $p(0)=a$, $p(n)=0$ for $n\neq 0$.  Multiplication is then defined just like multiplication for any two polynomials, as above.

Comment: I am interested in polynomials without numbers, which is why the question about multiplication. If $X$ is "cars" and $p$ is "color", then $p_0 + p_1 = green$ for example (addition is mixing colors), and $X^2 = hybrid car$ lets say (multiplication is combining the two cars), then $pX$ multiplication would be maybe "car color + color" for example. So the multiplication operator is defined differently for the combo of two different types.

Comment: Well you can assign whatever meaning you want to these symbols, but mathematically they're just formal expressions.

Comment: But how is the multiplication defined between two different type elements, however you want?

Comment: It is defined exactly how I wrote in the answer: it's all just formal symbols.  Is there some part of it you don't understand?

Comment: Ok so $X$ is not part of a set, it's just an arbitrary expression. I am wondering what an example of $X^n$ looks like that's not numbers then. Something like $f(a, b, c)^2 = f(a, b, c) \ast f(a, b, c) = ?$. At some point $X$ will have to _return a value of a specific type_, wondering if that is a correct assumption.

Comment: $X$ is not a placeholder here.  It literally is the letter $X$.  $X$ does not represent an arbitrary expression, but just the letter $X$.  An element of $K[X]$ is a polynomial expression _whose variable_ is the letter $X$.

Comment: Maybe your background as a computer scientist is throwing up some blocks to your forming the correct mental picture, @LancePollard. If this is the case, I recommend highly thinking of a polynomial as a function $p$ from $\Bbb N$ to $K$, just as Eric says in this answer.